# Cassandra 2 node cluster configuration issue

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, datastax

I am trying to configure a 2 node Cassandra cluster on my 2 laptops. The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed Cassandra using Datastax Community using the below command:-

```
sudo apt-get install dsc22 cassandra=2.2.4
```

After installation I have stopped the Cassandra server and cleared the initial data with the following command:-

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*
```

Then I wanted to initialize the multi node cluster (in my case 2 nodes). I followed this [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html) for doing so. Basically the changes I made are the following in cassandra.yaml file

```
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
     - seeds: "10.0.0.4"
listen_address:
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

I decided to make one of the node as seed as can be seen above.

I have made the above changes on both the machines. When I try to start Cassandra on my seed machine, it fails to start. Any pointers on how to resolve this? Also where can I find the Cassandra logs?

**UPDATED**

The following error is seen in system.log:-
ERROR [main] 2016-01-12 18:08:03,656 CassandraDaemon.java:651 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [concurrent_materialized_view_writes, enable_scripted_user_defined_functions, hints_flush_period_in_ms, max_hints_file_size_in_mb] from your cassandra.yaml
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader$MissingPropertiesChecker.check(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:162) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:115) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:504) [apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:638) [apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error on terminal. Where can I find the logs?

Comment: `/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log` and `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`

Comment: @Ralf, I have edited the main question with the error.

Comment: It's pretty clear, is it not? You ended up with an invalid cassandra.yaml. To me it looks like you picked up the yaml file from an other Cassandra version. In the 2.2.4 yaml there is no attributes concurrent_materialized_view_writes, etc.

Comment: Cool that worked. But it's a bit strange. I haven't picked the yaml file from other version. I actually edited the yaml file which got created through the installation process.

Comment: Possibly it is a packaging bug on Datastax's end? I use the tarball distributon from cassandra.apache.org and its cassandra.yaml does not contain those attributes.